# Is there a way to increase the metric limit on V4 of the API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I need to query for 15 metrics, but the API limits me to 10.  This appears to be a limit imposed by V3 when the API was GET based and the url length was an issue.  But V4 uses a POST.

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like it. I could not find exact documentation on it, but when using the API's Explorer, it gave me the following error:

**Request**

`POST https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet?fields=reports&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

**Response**

`{
 "error": {
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Requested 15 metrics; only 10 are allowed.",
  "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
 }
}`

Comment: The documentation i found that mentioned this, was for v3, but i cant find anything about it in v4

Comment: Yeah, I don't know if there is documentation on the limit yet for V4.

Answer (score 0):

Be it V3 or V4, limits on number of dimensions and metrics you can pass in API request is the same.
So, you can pass maximum 7 dimensions and 10 metrics only in a single API request.

The `workaround to get data for 15 metrics would be to send two requests to API (one with 10 metrics and one with 5 metrics) and then join both the responses`.

Comment: this seems to be the only current way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use two separate requests if you have 15 metrics. a general approach would be to split list of all metrics into `groups of 10` , python code:

`l <- some large list of metrics`

```
max_metric_size = 10

group_of_metrics = [l[i:i + max_metric_size] for i in xrange(0, len(l), max_metric_size)]
```

then something like :

```
for i in groups_of_metrics:
    # form your request body here and send request
```